# Sci-Fi short story, narrator is guy in limo, jobs assigned by your genetics

Tags: story-identification, genetics

This story is narrated by a guy in a limo. He lives in a world where jobs are assigned to you depending on your genetics and of all other humans. He is genetically assigned to enjoy all the other creations people make, e.g. clothes the limo, food, etc.

**What is the name of this story?**

Comment: When did you read the story/when might it have been released?

Comment: i may have read it online or in a scifi short stiry collecton,  im not sure.  i read it abiut 4 to 7 yrs ago.